# What is the difference between Bootplus and Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What are the advantages of [Bootplus](http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/) versus Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/)

> Bootplus provides the same basic templates form Bootstrap, adapted with the new "plus" style.
>
> Bootplus is built on top of Twitter Bootstrap as a customization that
> reproduce the most recent Google+ style.

So basically Bootstrap is used as Core for BootPlus. BootPlus provides more G+ style.